Handling strings with high Unicode codepoints (above U+FFFF)
In Kotlin, how can I iterate over a string that contains Unicode characters above U+FFFF?
Example code:
val s = "Hëllø! € "
for (c in s) {
    println("$c ${c.code}")
}

Actual output:
H 72
ë 235
l 108
l 108
ø 248
! 33
  32
€ 8364
  32
� 55357
� 56832

Desired output:
H 72
ë 235
l 108
l 108
ø 248
! 33
  32
€ 8364
  32
 128512


The Iterator implementation shown in the duplicate target should already do what you want. My answer there goes one step further and combines all the combining marks into a single element too (which you might want to do as well).

@Sweeper your duplicate could be the answer the OP needs, but it's not the question he's asked. He is not asking about combining characters. His question can be simply answered thus: Replace for (c in s) with for (c in s.codePoints()).

@k314159 I’ll wait for OP to respond. If OP doesn’t want combining characters and ZWJ sequences to be combined, I’m happy to reopen.

@k314159 You offer half the solution. For a full solution I had to change the body of the loop to var i = IntArray(1); i[0] = c; println("${String(i, 0, 1)} $c").  This compiles with kotlinc, but with Kotlin/Native I get errors like unresolved reference 'codePoints'. Both using Kotlin version 2.0.21.

The This question already has an answer here refers to a completely different issue.

@PeterKleiweg yes, another solution (not involving arrays) is println("${buildString { appendCodePoint(c) }} $c)". I think Kotlin/Native doesn't fully support Unicode due to lack of suitable methods to handle it.

In Kotlin/JVM, strings are encoded in UTF-16. (To be precise, they may be encoded internally using Latin1 but they still behave externally as if they're encoded in UTF-16.) This means that they're made up of 16-bit characters. To get the actual Unicode code points, including those above U+FFFF, you can use Java's codePoints() method:
val s = "Hëllø! € "
for (cp in s.codePoints()) {
    println("${buildString { appendCodePoint(cp) }} $cp")
}

Output:
H 72
ë 235
l 108
l 108
ø 248
! 33
  32
€ 8364
  32
 128512

However, be aware of the presence of combining characters, where multiple Unicode code points are used to make a single grapheme. If you want to support combining characters, then my answer will not help: you will need to look at Sweeper's answer in this question instead.
Unfortunately, on other platforms, Kotlin currently doesn't make it easy to handle Unicode. See this discussion for a list of currently open issues.
